# Turning Glass screen on and off

Tags: google-glass

I am writing a native Glass app using the Android SDK.

The app provides step-by-step instructions for use in a completely hands-free situation.

Using the sensor I am able to detect nods of the head (up, down, left and right).

I'd like to be able to wake the screen when nodding down to come back to the instructions.

I'm able to do this by setting a wake lock onCreate and releasing it when I nod up (and the screen sleeps). I then reset the wake lock to turn the screen on when I nod down.

The issue with this approach is that I need to keep the sensor on while the app is stopped in order to recognize the nod down and wake the screen. I assume that from a battery standpoint, leaving the sensor on for this is far from ideal especially since when I finally exit out of the app (using the down swipe) my app is not destroyed so I can't know to turn the sensor off at that time.

Will the GDK include a way for app to manage this sort of hands free interaction without leaving the sensor running?

Comment: can you please share your code to detect Nodding ? I want to develop a test application for nodding ... Please....

Comment: @Dr. aNdRO, my code predates the GDK so I don't think it makes sense to share at the moment. I'll try to find time to update it and post it online.